# gtk events: select in treeview before focus in event

Tags: haskell, treeview, gtk

i have the impression that a treeview gets the cursor changed event before it gets the focus in event. my code (in haskell, but i assume this is very similar to other language bindings):

```
    iResult2 <- builderGetObject builder castToTreeView (t2s "titleView")
    on iResult2 focusInEvent $ do
                    putIOwordsT ["------------------title view focus in"]
                    return False
    on  iResult2 cursorChanged   $ do
                    putIOwordsT ["-----------iResult selection"]
```

"titleView" is a treeview in a window with other widgets; if i click on a line in the treeview, i get the cursorChangedEvent and can read the line selected. only AFTERWARDS i get the focusInEvent (preceeded by the corresponding focusOutEvent of the previous entry with focus).

this is not what is expected (a selection can be made only after the focus is in the widget) and makes my program logic complicated. i assumed to have the focusOutEvent of the previous entry before the cursorChangedEvent in order to save the data in this entry before it is written over by the selected new data.

is there a way to influence the order of the events?

is that an intentional behaviour or a bug?